# How to display the woocommerce product tags of only featured product or recent product.

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to display the tags of the specific product. for example, if the user selects the recent products I need to display the tags of only recent products or if the user selects the featured products I need to display the tags of only featured product. 
anyone, there to help me out with this problem.
  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function get_the_terms() to ger WooCommerce 'product_tag' based on product id this way:

You can replace get_the_id() by a dynamic product Id variable in your woocommerce loop

```
$output = array();

$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_tag' );

if( count($terms) > 0 ){
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
        $term_name = $term->name;
        $term_slug = $term->slug;
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'product_tag' );
        $output[] = '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term_name.'</a>';
    }
    $output = implode( ', ', $output );
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: how can I get a term (product_tag)  of featured category only

Comment: @saagar you have to add above code in you WordPress loop so you get id of your product